# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'true' for column 'isVisible'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending data with FormData object to my laravel backend, issue is I have a checkbox input which is causing me trouble, my backend logs the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'true' for column 'isVisible' ...
```

In my migrations isVisible field is declared as a boolean:

```
$table->boolean('isVisible')->default(false);
```

If I hack into the payload and send an 1 instead of 'true' or 0 instead of 'false' my Post entry is created succesfully.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Send value as 1 or 0 or change it in controller before saving to DB.

Comment: Or use `TRUE`/`FALSE` without quotes. By quoting the values, you're sending them as strings as boolean values.

Comment: Please take a look at your database table. The datatype for `isVisible` should be `tinyint` with the length `1` and default value `0`. Now you can store the values either by using `TRUE` or `FALSE` or even `1` or `0` WITHOUT QUOTING.

Answer (score 0):

Send this before database

```php
$isVisible === true || strtolower($isVisible) == 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a nice solution for this:

```
$model->is_visible = $request->has('isVisible');
```

(if the checkbox is not checked, it will not be present in the $request bag, so the 'has' function will output false. If checked, it returns true (as boolean).